# How to run a rspec class multiple times with different parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, parameter-passing

I have a rspec class with set of tests. I want to run the same rspec test class multiple time with different parameters. Is it possible in rspec? If so, can someone help me with an example.

```
describe 'run test' do
  param = ''

  it 'xyz' do
    ...
    puts param
    ...
  end

  it 'abc' do
    ...
    puts param
    ...
  end

end
```

So, I want to run this rspec class multiple times with different values of param.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you, please, share your complete test code? Using global variables should be avoided wherever applicable since it's not a good practice. I can suggest a more suitable solution I find out more about intent of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

spec files are just ruby files so you can just wrap them around in a block if you have a fixed set of param values.  The following code should run ok.

```
1.upto(5) do |num|
  describe 'test' do
    it { expect(num).not_to eq(0) }
  end
end
```